# why does <myproject>/accounts/profile/ show the <myproject>/profile/ page

Tags: django, django-urls, django-allauth

Using django-allauth, after a successful login a user is redirected to `http://<myproject>/accounts/profile/`... However this URL doesn't exists, but yet it still successfully shows view from `http://<myproject>/profile/`

**settings.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url('album/', include('albums.urls')),
    url('profile/', include('user_profile.urls')),
]
```

**user_profile\urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

using `show_urls` I don't see anything for `/accounts/*` which would call the `view.profile` view

```
/accounts/confirm-email/        allauth.account.views.EmailVerificationSentView account_email_verification_sent
/accounts/confirm-email/<key>/  allauth.account.views.ConfirmEmailView  account_confirm_email
/accounts/email/        allauth.account.views.EmailView account_email
/accounts/inactive/     allauth.account.views.AccountInactiveView       account_inactive
/accounts/login/        allauth.account.views.LoginView account_login
/accounts/logout/       allauth.account.views.LogoutView        account_logout
/accounts/password/change/      allauth.account.views.PasswordChangeView        account_change_password
/accounts/password/reset/       allauth.account.views.PasswordResetView account_reset_password
/accounts/password/reset/done/  allauth.account.views.PasswordResetDoneView     account_reset_password_done
/accounts/password/reset/key/<uidb36>-<key>/    allauth.account.views.PasswordResetFromKeyView  account_reset_password_from_key
/accounts/password/reset/key/done/      allauth.account.views.PasswordResetFromKeyDoneView      account_reset_password_from_key_done
/accounts/password/set/ allauth.account.views.PasswordSetView   account_set_password
/accounts/signup/       allauth.account.views.SignupView        account_signup
/accounts/social/connections/   allauth.socialaccount.views.ConnectionsView     socialaccount_connections
/accounts/social/login/cancelled/       allauth.socialaccount.views.LoginCancelledView  socialaccount_login_cancelled
/accounts/social/login/error/   allauth.socialaccount.views.LoginErrorView      socialaccount_login_error
/accounts/social/signup/        allauth.socialaccount.views.SignupView  socialaccount_signup
```

only the actual /profile/ url...

```
/profile/       user_profile.views.profile      profile
```

help me to understand why `/accounts/profile/` is showing the `/profile/` view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `profile` url path is not being limited to match only the start of the url:

```
    url('profile/', include('user_profile.urls')),
```

This will match anything like `gibberishprofile/` for example, including `accounts/profile/`. If you change the url config to

```
    url('^profile/', include('user_profile.urls')),  # note the ^ before profile
```

Then only `profile/` will match.

Answer (score 5):

Actually redirecting to `/accounts/profile/` is default behavior in django. In django global settings, it is defined as `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. Django expects you to implement this page/url. Django `django-allauth` also uses same setting to redirect user after login.

If you want to redirect to any other page like `/profile/`, override this setting in your project settings.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/'
```

Or if you want `django-allauth` not to redirect at all set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = False` in your settings as described [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

Comment: Right. I understand that. But I dont see where I implemented that view in any of my urls.py.. so that's why I'm confused as to why that view is being rendered

Comment: Is it redirecting to `/profile/` or rendering same page as `/profile/` on `/accounts/profile/`?

Comment: The url shown is /accounts/profile. So it's not redirecting, but rendering